# Reading envelopes from Docusign REST API for specific user ID

Tags: rest, docusignapi

We have a requirement to read all the documents in Docusign using REST API, now I am able to read envelopes using folder names by passing folder name as query param to retrieve the envelope under that specific folder. however, we would need to pass user ID as a query parameter to the API instead of folders to read envelopes under given user.

Now once we read all the users, we are passing user ID as query param to retrieve envelopes.this is returning all the envelopes, this shows that the user ID param is not making any difference.

Is there any other way to read envelopes for a specific user?

Comment: by that you mean envelope SENT by that user? or SIGNED by that user?

Comment: Hi @InbarGazit How should I view the signed documents that has been already completed through API? I (as admin want to show/view particular envelop)

Comment: how are you using the API? do you use a client library?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [API to search for envelopes](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/envelopes/search) which allows you to filter your search in many different ways. In your case, you need to provide the userId that you wish to filter for. Here is a sample call (you can combine filters of course)

```
GET
/v2.1/accounts/4644/envelopes?user_id=a8a0cd4f-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-14a1a5c56f52
```

(the actual user_id should be the correct GUID for your user)